# Kivy access version number (App variable) outside main.py

Tags: python, kivy

I want to access the version number of my app outside the main.py. Is this possible to do this in foo.py **without** `import main.py`? What I tried:

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
__version__ = '0.4.0'

class KanjiOriginApp(App):
    app_version = StringProperty(__version__)
```

foo.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
print(App.app_version)
```

But this results in a: `AttributeError: type object 'App' has no attribute 'app_version'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `App.get_running_app().app_version` - the StringProperty gives instance-level behaviour, it doesn't modify the class definition of App itself.